# EF - Saving Parent Entity with Child

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 entities.....with a 1-0 relation (Documento and Archivo)

```
public class Documento
{
    public int DocumentoID { get; set; }
    public int? ExpedienteID { get; set; }
    public int? TipoDocumentoID { get; set; }
    public int? ArchivoID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaRegistro { get; set; }
    public int? Fojas { get; set; }
    public string Referencia { get; set; }
    public bool TieneArchivoFisico { get; set; }
    public DocumentoAdicional? Adicional { get; set; }
    public virtual Expediente Expediente { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoDocumento TipoDocumento { get; set; }
    public virtual Archivo Archivo { get; set; }

}

    public class Archivo
{
    public int ArchivoID { get; set; }
    public int DocumentoID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Resumen { get; set; }
    public byte[] DatosArchivo{ get; set; }

    public virtual Documento Documento { get; set; }

}
```

When I save this 2...they save correctly to the DB, but they are left unconnected.... This is the code I am using to save them:

```
public bool AdjuntarDocumentoAExpediente(Documento documento, string nombreArchivo, Stream streamArchivo, string descripcion, string resumen, out string mensajeError)
    {
        bool resultado = false;
        mensajeError = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (var contexto = new ModeloTC())
            {
                documento.TieneArchivoFisico = true;

                Archivo archivo = new Archivo();
                archivo.Documento = documento; //adding relation here

                archivo.Descripcion = descripcion;
                archivo.Nombre = nombreArchivo;
                archivo.Resumen = resumen;
                archivo.DatosArchivo = ConvertirStreamABytes(streamArchivo);

                contexto.Archivos.Add(archivo);
                contexto.SaveChanges();
                resultado = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mensajeError = "BLL AdjuntarDocumentoAExpediente:" + ex.GetBaseException().Message;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

The problem is...that after executing this method, this is how my DB data looks like....

```
Table Archivo
ArchivoID   DocumentoID Nombre  Descripcion Resumen DatosArchivo
5   0   C:\Users\test\justafilename.txt lalala  lalalalala  

Table Documento
DocumentoID ExpedienteID    ArchivoID   FechaRegistro   .....
5   1   NULL    2014-11-06 .....
```

As you can see, the DocumentoID in the Archivo table has 0 as value......and the ArchivoID in the Documento table has NULL...... both entities were saved correctly, except for the relationship...... I have no idea why this happens....

Comment: But you notice that ArchivoID and DocumentoID as both 5 as xxxId ? Looks like EF created a pk / fk...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have documentoid in archivo and archivoid in documento. Also documento virtual property in archivo and archivo virtual property in documento.  This is a circular dependency so ef couldn't create the relationship. You need to remove one of them depending upon which is primary table and which is child table.